# Синтаксический анализатор для уравнений с неизвестной

Tags: pascal, синтаксический-анализ

Необходимо на **pascal** сделать анализатор для произвольного выражения, вводимого **в ручную** пользователем, и содержащего одну неизвестную. Результатом работы данного анализатора должно быть значение введённого выражения. Например, пользователь вводит *sqrt(x)-1* при *x = 1*. В результате мы получаем 0

В интернете я нашёл код анализатора для калькулятора. Я долго старался изменить его под свои нужды, но знаний паскаля мне не хватает. Вот сам код:

```
program Calculator;

var
    ans     : real;
    S       : string;
    ErrPos  : integer;
    Mess    : string;

procedure Calc(S: string;
    var V: real;
    var ErrPos: integer;
    var ErrMess: string
    );
const
    EOT = #0;

type 
    Functions = (ABSOLUTE, SQUARE, TRUNCATE,
                 ROUNDING, SINUS, COSINUS, ARC,
                 LOG, EXPONENT, SQUAREROOT,
                 DUMMY
                 );
const
    FirstFunc = ABSOLUTE;
    LastFunc = SQUAREROOT; 
    FuncNames: array[Functions] of string[6] =
                    ('ABS', 'SQR', 'TRUNC', 'ROUND',
                     'SIN', 'COS', 'ARCTAN', 'LN',
                     'EXP', 'SQRT', ''
                    );
var 
    i   : integer;
    Ch  : char;

procedure Error(Message: string);
begin
    if ErrPos = 0 then begin
        ErrMess := Message;
        ErrPos := i;
        Ch := EOT;
    end;
end;

procedure NextChar;
begin
    if ErrPos <> 0 then
        Ch := EOT
    else
        repeat
            i := i + 1;
            if i <= length(S) then
                Ch := UpCase(S[i])
            else 
                Ch := EOT;
        until Ch <> ' ';
end;

procedure Number(var V: real);
var 
    NumStr  : string; {Текст числа}
    Err     : integer; {Номер неверного символа}

procedure IntNumber;
begin  
    if not(Ch in ['0'..'9']) then
        Error('Число начинается не с цифры');
    while Ch in ['0'..'9'] do begin
        NumStr := NumStr + Ch;
        NextChar;
    end;
end;
begin
    NumStr := '';
    IntNumber;
    if Ch = '.' then begin
        NumStr := NumStr + Ch;
        NextChar;
        IntNumber;
    end;
    if Ch = 'E' then begin
        NumStr := NumStr + Ch;
        NextChar;
        if Ch in ['+','-'] then begin
            NumStr := NumStr + Ch;
            NextChar;
        end;
        IntNumber;
    end;
    Val(NumStr, V, Err);
    if Err <> 0 then
        Error('Ошибка в числе');
end;

procedure Name(var F: Functions);
var 
    NameStr : string;
begin
    if Ch in ['A'..'Z'] then begin
        NameStr := Ch;
        NextChar;
        end
    else
        Error('Ожидается буква');
    while Ch in ['A'..'Z', '0'..'9'] do begin
        NameStr := NameStr + Ch;
        NextChar;
    end;

    F := FirstFunc;
    while (F <= LastFunc) and (NameStr <> FuncNames[F]) do
        F := succ(F);
    if F = DUMMY then
        Error('Неправильное имя функции');
end;

function Func(F: Functions; ans: real) : real;
begin
    Func := ans;
    case F of
    ABSOLUTE    : Func := abs(ans);
    SQUARE      : Func := sqr(ans);
    TRUNCATE    : Func := trunc(ans);
    ROUNDING    : Func := round(ans);
    SINUS       : Func := sin(ans);
    COSINUS     : Func := cos(ans);
    ARC         : Func := arctan(ans);
    LOG         : 
        if ans > 0 then
            Func := ln(ans)
        else
            Error('Логарифм неположительного числа');
    EXPONENT    : Func := exp(ans);
    SQUAREROOT  :
        if ans >= 0 then 
            Func := sqrt(ans)
        else 
            Error('Корень из отрицательного числа');
    end;
end;

procedure Expression(var V: real); forward;

procedure Multiplier(var V: real);
var
    F : Functions;
begin
    if Ch in ['0'..'9'] then
        Number(V)
    else if Ch in ['A'..'Z'] then begin
        Name(F);
        if Ch <> '(' then
            Error('Ожидается ''(''')
        else begin
            NextChar;
            Expression(V);
            V := Func(F, V);
            if Ch = ')' then
                NextChar
            else
                Error('Ожидается '')''')
            end
         end
    else if Ch = '(' then begin
        NextChar;
        Expression(V);
        if Ch <> ')' then
            Error('Ожидается '')''')
        else 
            NextChar
        end
    else
        Error('Ожидается число, функция или ''(''');
end;

procedure Addend(var V: real);
var 
    Op  : char;     {Знак операции}
    X   : real;     {Значение операнда}
begin
    Multiplier(V);
    while Ch in ['*','/'] do begin
        Op := Ch;
        NextChar;
        Multiplier(X);
        if Op = '*' then
            V := V * X
        else if X <> 0 then
            V := V / X
        else
            Error('Деление на ноль');
        end;
end;

procedure Expression(var V: real);
var 
    Op  : char;
    X   : real;
begin
    Op := '+';
    if Ch in ['+','-'] then begin
        Op := Ch;
        NextChar;
    end;
    Addend(V);
    if Op = '-' then
        V := -V;
    while Ch in ['+','-'] do begin
        Op := Ch;
        NextChar;
        Addend(X);
        if Op = '+' then
            V := V + X
        else
            V := V - X
    end;
end;

begin
    ErrPos := 0;
    i := 0;
    NextChar;
    Expression(V);
    if Ch <> EOT then
        Error('Ожидается конец выражения');
end;

begin
    WriteLn('Формульный калькулятор');
    repeat
        Write('?');
        ReadLn(S);
        Calc(S, ans, ErrPos, Mess);
        if ErrPos > 0 then begin
            WriteLn('^':ErrPos + 1);
            WriteLn(Mess);
            end
        else if abs(ans) > 0.0001 then
            WriteLn(ans:15:6)
        else
            WriteLn(ans);
    until S = '';
end.
```

Comment: А икс можно сразу подставить

Comment: Нет. Заменить все "х" в строке и подставить строку в процедуру Calc нельзя.

Comment: Почему?)) по условию подходит. Ну или опишите "ваши нужды" - в вопросе их не увидел

Comment: Это занимает слишком много времени, как мне кажется. Вообще, мне нужно построить график по введённому пользователем выражению. Значение "х" в каждой итерации увеличивается на 0.01. "x" находится в интервале от -10 до 10, так что это 2000 итераций цикла. Предложенное вами решение я пробовал использовать, однако ничего не вышло - график лишь отдалённо похож на себя.